# Error page but Rails log says everything's fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

One of my clients is getting the standard "Something went wrong" error page on the production server, however the production.log claims that the page was rendered correctly.

```
Started GET "/translations" for **IP** at 2012-06-07 08:30:56 +0000
Processing by TranslationsController#index as HTML
  Rendered translations/_filters.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered glossary_terms/_form.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered translations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (125.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 119.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
```

I have verified that this is indeed her request being logged, and that she shift-reloaded the page. Also, I cannot reproduce the error locally; the page loads fine for me and several other people.

Comment: You might want to give more information, as we cannot solve 'An error' with the amount of information you provide...

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I only see the standard Rails error page and the log claims that everything is fine. Not asking you to solve the problem, but to give me some ideas of what could possibly create this discrepancy between reporting & actual state, or how I could find more information on the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's one of those bugs** where you have to go and enumerate all those things that are different between your environment and the clients.  Check things like:

- Cookies
- Session state
- Browser version (the response might be a 200, but it might be malformed)
- Use Sam Spade to view the raw response - might be a clue in there
- Double check that it is her request being logged
- Can she reproduce it without fail?
- Has she tried with different browsers?  Different machine?
- Maybe the 'something went wrong' error is being served as a 200 response?

Comment: I thought it was fixed, but no. Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054049/very-limited-502-bad-gateway-error-in-rails