# Very limited 502 Bad Gateway error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is so weird.

One of my clients has been consistently getting 502 Bad Gateway errors (without fail and in every browser), but only on one particular page of my Rails site, she can access the rest of the pages normally. Also, everybody else (including people on the same company network) can access the same page fine. Also, the production.log does not contain any trace of an error, it says the page was rendered 200 OK. What could possibly be causing this???

EDIT: I have double-checked that other Rails errors, such as trying to call up the details of a product id that doesn't exist, result in a 404 error instead.

Comment: A 502 may have nothing to do with your app internally, as it indicates an invalid response was received from another server while trying to process the client's request.

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy (like nginx) in front of the Rails server? If so, check those logs.

Comment: Have you visited the client and watched the error happen in situ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. This was an error with page headers (session object -> cookie) getting too large. I'm using Facebook authentication and was storing the Facebook user session in the session object. For this one person, her personal information on Facebook was too long, so that she was getting this error while everybody else was fine. I fixed the error by only storing the Facebook ID in the session object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue for few pages alone which is weird and adding below settings to the nginx.conf fixed it

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```

Hope that helps